# Gatsby source filesystem name option

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have this import:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
        name: `Duck`,
        path: `${__dirname}/../static/content/collections/posts`
    }
}
```

I can see in Graphiql that it generates `allDucks` but, when queried, nothing comes through. When I query `allMarkdownRemark` though, I can see the posts.

How do I query with `allDucks` instead of `allMarkdownRemark`? Why is `allDucks` there anyway - if it's empty?